# What's difference between reservor and reservee?

Tags: meaning, differences

Reservee is described as: One to, or for, whom anything is reserved.

Reservor is described as: One who reserves; a reserver.

So, if Alice reserves Bob a room in a hotel, then Alice is a reservor of the room, and Bob is a reservee of the room? (is this understanding correct?)

Comment: I think your interpretation is correct. It's also possible that the reservor and reservee are the same person (e.g. making a reservation for your own use).

Comment: See [here](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/32258/suffixes-ee-vs-or/226322) - "Suffixes -ee vs -or"

Comment: Please note that resevor, and reservee are extremely rare in English, see the Google Ngram results for **reservor,reservee,kumquat,ectasis** https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reservor%2Creservee%2Ckumquat%2Cectasis&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creservor%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creservee%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ckumquat%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cectasis%3B%2Cc0

Comment: It sounds like Payer and Payee.

Comment: @Greybeard well, they are only words I found matching exact meaning I need,... I need generic term for "one to/for whom is something reserved". And, thank you for the utility, I didn't know about Google Ngram.

Comment: I have gone sixty years as a native speaker without meeting these words. It is obvious to me what they mean, but they are not words that a non-native speaker should ever use. I suggest that you give us your sentence, and we can rephrase it for you.

Comment: @TonyK it's term for an attribute of an object in software,... where one object contains information about reservation of stuff, and reservee can be more-or-less anything.

Comment: Ah, OK. In software, anything goes.